# Remembering data loaded via ajax 'load more' when using the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Just looking at creating a feature to remember data that has been loaded via an ajax load more button when the user leaves the page and returns via a back button.

The way i was thinking is:

- When the user loads more data, a parameter is added to the url e.g ?more=1
- When the page is loaded, it checks for a more parameter and then runs the query depending on that

My query currently returns 16 new results, so i could simply do the 'value of more x 16' and then use that as the last parameter in the LIMIT claus.

This shouldn't affect the new data being loaded as i already specifiy the url in the ajax.

Is this the correct way around this? Or another simpler way?

Craig

Comment: Sounds as good as any. Can you check out using HTML5 localStorage so that you don't have to get the data again. Just a simple workaround you can use to reduce network latency, as long as you don't care about the freshness of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
When the page is loaded, it checks for a more parameter and then runs
 the query depending on that
```

If it runs the query depending on that parameter you aren't really caching the results.

If you want to remember that data to speed up page loading you should, after a query, calculate html corresponding to the additional data and save it in a file.

Then, if the same parameter is present in the url (and if those files exist), you can include the preformatted data from the cache files.